# Excluding package with maven-compiler-plugin works for one package but doesn't work for another

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

My project has the following package structure:

```
src/
  com.my.app.school.course
    -Course.java
    ...

  com.my.app.school.course.free
    -CourseFree.java
```

I use Maven to build the project, in my pom.xml, I defined [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to test excluding a package with all its java classes.

I first tried following way to **exclude** package `com.my.app.school.course.free`:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/my/app/school/course/free/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**It works!** I mean after run `mvn clean install`, the final build under target/classes/ doesn't have the package `com/my/app/school/course/free` .

Then, I tried to exclude package `com.my.app.school.course` . I simply **replace** the above `<exclude>` tag with value `<exclude>**/com/my/app/school/course/*</exclude>`. I thought it should work too , but it doesnt!  Under target/classes/ I see all packages, no package is excluded. Why?

What I want to achieve is to exclude package `com.my.app.school.course` but keep pacakge `com.my.app.school.course.free` , how to achieve this?

**======== update ========**

I feel it might be because the package I tried to exclude contain java classes that have been used in other packages. I will verify my guess.

Comment: are you sure you have clean build?

Comment: @AdrianShum, I always run with "mvn clean install"

Comment: I tried a similar case and it worked well for me.  Maven 3.0.5, Compiler plugin 2.3.2.

Comment: I feel it might be because the package I tried to exclude contain java classes which have been used in other package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason why the exclusion doesn't work.

Because some java classes under the package which I tried to exclude have been used in other packages. Seems maven-compiler-plugin is smart to detect that.

Comment: This is the default behaviour of the java compiler which works exactly like this.

Comment: Is there a way to force the exclusion?

Comment: @Linuslabo, configure your exclusions in the _maven-jar-plugin_ instead.

Comment: Definitely was worth trying though.  This would be useful to exclude something from a Sonar scan perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the problem is that your *other* sources depend on some of the sources you've excluded: Because Maven passes `-sourcepath` to javac, javac can find and compile those "missing" sources.

If you want the build to fail in that case, you can explicitly specify a dummy value for `-sourcepath`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-sourcepath</arg>
      <arg>doesnotexist</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See [MCOMPILER-174](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-174) and [this longer explanation of how javac handles `-sourcepath` and other arguments](https://blog.ltgt.net/most-build-tools-misuse-javac/#what-does-maven-do-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

configuring the **exclusion in the *jar*** or ***war plugins*** seems to be a good technique to not disturb JUnit testing and compilation:

[`maven-jar-plugin` / `exclude`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/service/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[`maven-war-plugin` / `exclude`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>
      WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-*.jar,
      %regex[WEB-INF/lib/log4j-(?!over-slf4j).*.jar]
    </packagingExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```