# Maven compile plugin package exclusion doesn't work

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a project that is built against 3 versions of dependencies. The oldest version has many incompatible changes which prompts me to exclude the only package that use them:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>spark-1.3.1</id>
        <properties>
            <spark.version>1.3.1</spark.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <testExcludes>
                            <testExclude>**/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/**</testExclude>
                        </testExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

However, when I execute any maven command after compile with -Pspark-1.3.1 parameter, I still receive the error information on all scala files in the excluded package:

```
[INFO] Compiling 54 Scala sources and 9 Java sources to /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/target/scala/classes...
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/GoogleSearchTransformer.scala:28: not found: value setDefault
[ERROR]   setDefault(Pages -> 0, PageCol -> null, IndexCol -> null)
[ERROR]   ^
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/GoogleSearchTransformer.scala:37: not found: value getOrDefault
[ERROR]       .wgetExplore(S"div#foot a:contains(Next)", maxDepth = getOrDefault(Pages), depthKey = $(PageCol), optimizer = Narrow)
[ERROR]                                                             ^
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/TransformerLike.scala:19: value defaultCopy is not a member of com.tribbloids.spookystuff.pipeline.TransformerLike
[ERROR]   def copy(extra: ParamMap): TransformerLike = this.defaultCopy(extra)
[ERROR]                                                     ^
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/TransformerLike.scala:26: value defaultCopy is not a member of com.tribbloids.spookystuff.pipeline.SpookyTransformer
[ERROR]   override def copy(extra: ParamMap): SpookyTransformer = this.defaultCopy(extra)
[ERROR]                                                                ^
[ERROR] /home/peng/git/spookystuff/core/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spookystuff/pipeline/TransformerLike.scala:31: not found: value getOrDefault
[ERROR]     val colName = Option(getOrDefault(col))
```

What is the cause of this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25323258/1743880

Comment: I have checked their post and it seems to be not applicable to my case: my excluded package is not used anywhere else, if I comment out all files in them the program can still compile

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, turn out that my code is written in Scala and I have to do the same in maven-scala-plugin.